# Elastic search - search api query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have an index named "bank"(added from this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_exploring_your_data.html)), with sample data like:

```
{
      "account_number" : 25,
      "balance" : 40540,
      "firstname" : "Virginia",
      "lastname" : "Ayala",
      "age" : 39,
      "gender" : "F",
      "address" : "171 Putnam Avenue",
      "employer" : "Filodyne",
      "email" : "virginiaayala@filodyne.com",
      "city" : "Nicholson",
      "state" : "PA"
}
```

When I do [request body search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html) it works for some keys and for some it doesn't. For e.g

```
GET /bank/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : {"age" : 39}
    }
}
```

Above request works, while the below one doesn't return any response(0 response)

```
GET /bank/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : {"firstname" : "Virginia"}
    }
}
```

What is reason for above? What should be done to fetch the result based on any keys

Comment: This might be rooted in String querys: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/query-string-doesnt-work-correctly/78690

Comment: What is the `mapping` of `firstname` field ?

Comment: @ArelSapir: May be, Confusion is for some keys(with string values) it work, but for most it doesn't work. Even the example provided in request body search works fine: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For string fields, it will pass the string through the standard analyzer which lowercases it. For instance, the standard analyzer would turn the string **“Quick Brown Fox!”** into the terms **[quick, brown, fox]**. This is why your query doesn't work.

You can solve this using :

- Setting fields as `not analyzed`
- Use the `match` query instead, which understands how the field has been analyzed.